# cannot access to annotated spring service

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm trying to access @Service defined class

Interfaces are defined, here is an implementation

```
    @Service
    public class TypeServiceImpl implements TypeService {

        @Autowired
        TypeDAO dao;

        public List<DocType> findAll() {
    System.out.println("accessing findAll"); //have no appearence
    return dao.findAll();
}
```

public TypeDAOImpl()
    {
        System.out.println("Constructing TypeDAOImpl");
    }

```
...

}
```

code for DAO:

```
@Repository
public class TypeDAOImpl extends BaseDAO<Type, Long> implements TypeDAO{

}
```

BaseDAO:

```
public class BaseDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericDAOImpl<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

used [generic dao](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/)
configuration for app loads fine(no warn or err), but when I'm trying to use service:

```
@Autowired
private TypeService TypeService;
public void init() {

        try {
            for (Type d : TypeService.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(d.getType());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

in applicationContext:

```
<!-- Use annotations (@Autowired) for property injection -->
    <context:annotation-config />
```

in logs:
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14db0e3: ... typeDAOImpl,appMain, typeServiceImpl

my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/config/application-context.xml,classpath:/config/datasource-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>
    Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>myapp.main.MainApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

stack trace is "very informational" (I used vaadin as web framework)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.AppMain.init(AppMain.java:26)
    at com.vaadin.Application.start(Application.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.startApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1001)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:411)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any suggestions?

I added constructors for GenericDAOHibernate and TypeDAOImpl, so as I understand, these beans are initialized
...
12.10.2009 12:57:48 org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl 
INFO: building session factory
12.10.2009 12:57:48 org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
**Constructing Generic DAO
Constructing TypeDAOImpl**
12.10.2009 12:57:48 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
...

I don't understand because this config worked with ZK..

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have the appropriate namespaces added to your Spring app context?

Comment: Could you add the stackstrace?

Comment: I've asked that in a comment below and, based on stack trace above, I'll ask again - is AppMain (which is presumably from where the last code sample above - the one with `init()` method is) defined as a bean  in your context? Because if not, how do you expect auto-wiring to work for it?

Comment: I tried to define AppMain with following annotations:
@Configurable(preConstruction = true) 
@Service and @Component

Comment: How to you load the spring context as a servlet filter or web application listener? Is AppMain initiated by spring or vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you've posted is rather inconsistent.

`findAll()` method is not declared anywhere; plus service implementation implements `Service` but you're trying to autowire it into `TypeService` which is not going to work.

If the first code fragment was instead written as:

```
@Service
public class TypeServiceImpl implements TypeService {
```

and it was the only `TypeService` implementation in your app context, auto-wiring would have worked.

Comment: findAll() declared in TypeServiceImpl:
public List<DocType> findAll() {
  System.out.println("accessing findAll"); //not appears!!
  return dao.findAll();
 }

dao based on GenericDAOImpl

Comment: The code where you're trying to use the service (your last code snippet) - where is that coming from? Is it also a part of a bean declared in the **same** context?